# Problems sending images from my iPhone from one GMail account to another

Tags: iphone, gmail, ios

I recently came across a problem where I used to be able to send myself a photo from one Gmail account onto another Gmail account now I keep getting message undelivered. I deleted my Gmail account on my iPhone and set it up again still the same results. My iPhone is running on iOS 4.2.1.

Comment: How large is the photo?

Comment: quite small I use to email myself 2 to 3mb before not an issue with size I tried lowering the size under 1mb still the same thing :( it's the strangest thing can't figure it out.

Comment: I assume you tried restarting your iPhone as well? How are you adding your GMail account back? Are you on 3G or on Wifi?

Comment: I tried Both 3g and Wifi still doesn't work I can receieve regular mails with no problem so I know email works fine just sending myself stuff doesn't seem to like anymore..kinda weird